# filter an array inside of a array of objects with variable options - js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to let the user filter this array

```
const allProjects= [
     {
      id:1,
      name: 'Project A',
      comments: ['a','b'],
      tests: [
               {id:1, name:'test1', comments:['aa','bb']},
               {id:2, name:'abc', comments:['aa','bb']},
               {id:2, name: 'test2', comments: ['a','b']}
             ]
     },
     {
      id:2,
      name: 'Project B',
      comments: ['project comment1','project comment2'],
      tests: [
               {id:1, name:'test1', comments:['aa','bb']},
               {id:2, name:'abc', comments:['aa','bb']},
               {id:2, name: 'test2', comments: ['a','b']}
             ]
       }

   ]
```

What is the correct way to filter by variable options?

the options to filter by: project.name, project.comment, test.name, test.comment

for example filter by:

project.comment and test.comment

or by project.comment only

or test.name only

etc..

Code currently: Filter only by test name:

```
    const k = keyword.toLowerCase();
    let filtered;
    filtered = allProjects.map(x => Object.assign({}, x));
    filtered = filtered.filter((project) => {
      project.tests = project.tests.filter(
          (test)=> test.name.toLowerCase().includes(k));
        return project.tests.length>0
    });
    return filtered
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say something like this:

```
const filteredProjects = this.allProjects
  .filter(project => filterByName ? project.name.toLowerCase().includes(k) : true)
  .filter(project => filterByTestName ? project.tests.some(test => test.name.toLowerCase().includes(k)) : true)
  .filter(/***/);
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to create different compare functions to each field and add it to the `compareFn` props of the `filtering` object. They return  boolean based on the search condition fits the record or not. (I did not implement the compareFns.)
In the below example the user is searching the `t1` string.

```js
const allProjects= [
     {
      id:1,
      name: 'Project A',
      comments: ['a','b'],
      tests: [
               {id:1, name:'test1', comments:['aa','bb']},
               {id:2, name:'abc', comments:['aa','bb']},
               {id:2, name: 'test2', comments: ['a','b']}
             ]
     },
     {
      id:2,
      name: 'Project B',
      comments: ['project comment1','project comment2'],
      tests: [
               {id:1, name:'test1', comments:['aa','bb']},
               {id:2, name:'abc', comments:['aa','bb']},
               {id:2, name: 'test2', comments: ['a','b']}
             ]
       }

   ]
   
  const filtering = [
   {
      accessor: 'comments',
      searchValue: 't1',
      compareFn: (searchValue, record) => true
   },
   {
      accessor: 'tests.name',
      searchValue: 't1',
      compareFn: (searchValue, record) => true
    }
  ]
   
  const filterFn = (record) => (
    filtering.reduce((acc, { searchValue, compareFn }) => (
      acc && compareFn(searchValue, record)
    ),true)
  )
     
  console.log(allProjects.filter(filterFn))
```